# Save UIWebView ActiveElement for later use

Tags: javascript, iphone, uiwebview

I want the user to be able to scan a barcode into a webform from my iphone app. I have been achieving something similar with javascript this way.

```
NSString *javaScript = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"var textField = document.activeElement;"
                            "textField.value = '%@';" , barcode];
    [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:javaScript];
```

However when I use the camera scanner it has to load a new view and the webview looses focus. Is there a way to save the active elements ID for later so that when you return I can give that view focus again and possibly auto submit?

edit:

I've got it mostly working, here's what I've done.

```
self.activeElement = [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"function getTextField(){ var textField = document.activeElement.id; return textField; } getTextField();"];
```

That saves the textfield id to a string variable. Then when my app comes out of the camera view.

```
NSString *javaScript = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"var textField = document.getElementById('%@'); textField.value = '%@';" , self.activeElement, barcodeValueFromCamera];

[webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:javaScript];
```

And that puts in the value as expected... however if I try this.

```
[webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"document.getElementByID(%@).form.submit();", self.activeElement]];
```

It doesn't seem to submit the value. Any ideas? Also I've just been testing this on googles site....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out.

First save the activeElements ID by using a javascript function. (self.activeElement is just a NSString)

```
self.activeElement = [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"function getTextField(){ return document.activeElement.id; } getTextField();"];
```

In my case I'm using a camera barcode scanner... when I come back to the view (and the webview has lost focus) I use this code to put in the value and optionally submit the form.

```
[webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"document.getElementById('%@').value = '%@';" , self.activeElement, inputString]];

[webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"document.getElementById('%@').form.submit();", self.activeElement]];
```

Answer (score 1):

When you go back to the previous view, that is actually a new instance with default values.

You will need to save this value somewhere and load when the view is initialized.

For example, you can create a singleton with the values of the current state (or default values initially) of your program. Then, when you load the view you can get the information from this state. This way, before leaving the view you can set the values you want in this singleton, and load back when needed.

Another solution would be something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14309271/how-to-retain-uidatepicker-and-uitextfield-values-when-switching-view-controller).

Comment: I understand what you're saying but you misunderstood the question. I'm not trying to save the string but the text field the JavaScript found.

Comment: I was going to recommend the same solution you found. I had to do that on C++/Qt something similar. Unfortunately, I dont have points enough to Thumbs Up your answer.